# qTranslate-X issue with WP post date month name in Ukrainian

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding, qtranslate-x

I am using 3 languages: Ukrainian (default), English and Russian. The plug-in works perfectly, but the name of the month (in the date of comment or post) looks like �������. Everything else (including calendar in the widget) are translated correctly.

I have changed the text encoding in the browser to try to find out if it is the encoding issue and yes - the month's name is in KOI8-U - somehow.

Wordpress 4.9.4
qTranslate: 3.4.6.8

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for your note. I am sorry for broking rules. I will try to be much more attentive to the rules next time. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer which works for me:

[See **DaniilKZ's** answer here](https://github.com/qTranslate-Team/qtranslate-x/issues/536)

Here is a quote:

> Add the code to the function.php:
>
> remove_filter('get_the_time',
>   'qtranxf_timeFromPostForCurrentLanguage',0,3);
>   remove_filter('get_the_date',
>   'qtranxf_dateFromPostForCurrentLanguage',0,3);
>   remove_filter('get_the_modified_date',
>   'qtranxf_dateModifiedFromPostForCurrentLanguage',0,2);